# "Дитя": склоняется или нет?

Tags: склонение

Что-то никак не могу сообразить: мне кажется, или слово "дитя" не склоняется? Но разве для русского языка характерны несклоняемые слова?
И не для того ли в просторечии образовалось слово "дитё", чтобы его можно было свободно склонять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "дитя" относится к разносклоняемым существительным и имеет своеобразные падежные формы:
Род.п. -дитяти
Дат.п. - дитяти
Твор.п. -дитятею
предл.п - о дитяти
Дитё - это просторечное слово

Comment: >Твор.п. -дитятею   
  
Скорее - дитятей. Устаревающие формы на "-ею" употребляются в основном в поэтической речи. Тут некоторые словари грешат неактуальностью.

Answer (score 3):

О склонении уже сказали. Ниже я добавлю.

Интереснее форма "дитё". Дело в том, что *"дитя" - единственное в русском языке одушевленное существительное среднего рода*, да еще с непривычным для среднего рода окончанием -я. Некий аналог есть только у слов на -мя: вымя, темя и проч., и у них тоже протетические формы косвенных падежей, но другие.
От необычности формы и просторечное "дитё" - как стремление приблизить слово внешне к среднему роду. При этом оно начинает склоняться по вполне естественным правилам: дитя, дитю, дитём. Как сено или яблоко.

Теперь об одушевленности. Сей факт часто оспаривается, но это отдельный разговор. 
Виктор (вслед за большинством словарей) опустил самое интересное. Винительный падеж. Именно по нему можно определить грамматическую одушевлённость.
Так вот. Он сосуществует в двух вариантах. "Вижу дитя" и "Вижу дитятю". Последняя форма далеко не всеми признаётся правомерной, но она существует минимум как просторечная. 
Ну и самое главное. Множественное для "дитя" - дети. Одушевлённость не вызывает сомнений. "Вижу детей", никак не иначе. Так почему не "дитятю"?
Всё это, имхо, вполне доказывает одушевленность "дитяти". А через неё объясняет и многие заморочки с этим, вполне казалось бы - привычным, словом.

Answer (score 1):

*Дитё* мне нравится больше. Слово *дитятя* устарело.

Answer (score 1):

Сильное словоизменение объясняется тем, что в древности в корне слова "дитя" стояла особая буква "ять", которая в более современных версиях русского языка выражается чаще как "е", иногда как "и", возможно, в зависимости от ударения (а в украинском всегда как "i"; в белорусском - как "я"). Отсюда изменения корневой гласной в современном русском: "дитя", но и "дети".

- Именительный падеж (кто? что?) ед.ч. дитя мн.ч. дитята/дитяти/дети
- Родительный падеж (кого? чего?) ед.ч. дитяти мн.ч. дитят/дитят(ь,ей)/детей
- Дательный падеж (кому? чему?) ед.ч. дитяти/дитяте мн.ч. дитятам/дитятям/детям
- Винительный падеж (кого? что?) ед.ч. дитя мн.ч. дитят/дитят(ь,ей)/детей
- Творительный падеж (кем? чем?) ед.ч. дитятей мн.ч. дитятами/дитятями/детьми
- Предложный падеж (о ком? о чем?) ед.ч. дитяти/дитяте мн.ч. о дитятах/дитятях/детях

Похожим образом склонялись названия детёнышей многих живых существ, например, "теля". На Руси телёнок приравнивался к ребёнку, есть его мясо - телятину - считалось признаком некой ереси.
Слово "теля" однозначно среднего рода, и никак не мужского, это ошибка присваивать ему мужской род (правильно: "ласковое теля двух маток сосёт")

- Именительный падеж (кто? что?) теля телята
- Родительный падеж (кого? чего?) теляти телят
- Дательный падеж (кому? чему?) теляти/теляте телятам
- Винительный падеж (кого? что?) теля телят
- Творительный падеж (кем? чем?) телятей телятами
- Предложный падеж (о ком? о чем?) теляти/теляте о телятах

Рудименты такого "детского" склонения проглядывают в отдельных словоформах "порося/поросята" ("Не было у бабы забот, так купила..." (кого? что? вин. пад.) "...порося"), "котята", "лягушата" и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: 1) Что такое "сильное  словоизменение"? 2) Откуда вы взяли формы типа именительного множественного "дитяты"? 3) Какую парадигму Вы считаете правильной? У Вас слишком много вариантов без всякого разделения. Ну а каким боком тут корневой ять - это даже и спрашивать боюсь. Тем более, что его там никогда не было. Теленок, теля всегда писался через "есть".

Comment: Сильное словоизменение - это когда изменение в корне. Я считаю все варианты одинаково правильными, я сторонник демократического подхода. А где вы увидели, что теля через ять? теля как раз через е, поэтому вариантов словоформ меньше.

Comment: Допустим, хотя не понимаю зачем вводить такой термин.. Что он дает в ваших рассуждениях?!

Comment: Про ять. Вы же приводите теленок как аналогию детям,. но при этом говорите, что первопричина в корневом яте?! --- Ну а то, что все правильно - с этим я, конечно, не могу согласиться. Зачем тогда вообще учение о языке, если "все правильно"?

Comment: Ничего не даёт, а должен был? Спасибо за реакцию, в любом случае.

Comment: Ну да, должен.))  Бессмысленное нагромождение фактов (тем более - весьма сомнительных) тут не приветствуется.

Comment: А мне ваш ник сомнительным кажется, дальше что?))

Comment: Дальше - ничего. Ники тут не обсуждаются. А ответы, особенно новичков, подлежат проверки на предмет их адекватности.